# How to confirm whether crosswalk is integrated in iOS project or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, crosswalk-runtime

I tried to integrate the crosswalk in my existing iOS project by following the procedure `Extended WKWebView`. I have updated the pod file with

```
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'crosswalk-ios', '~> 1.2'
use_frameworks!
```

and here is the code that used in project

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    WKWebViewConfiguration *configuration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
    self.webview=[[XWalkView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:configuration];
    self.webview.scrollView.bounces=NO;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.webview];
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

But I am unable to confirm that the app is using the crosswalk in the project.
So, Could you please suggest me how to confirm that crosswalk is being used in the project.

Comment: You are using XWalkView. It is a class from Crosswalk framework. So if your code is compiling correctly then it is being used in your project.